# Function Creating Arrays Returning Work Information

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking to create a function that takes as input a CSV file. This file contains 4 columns and 30 rows of data. In my function I want to create a 2D array for each row of data that exists in the file, where the x-coordinate is the information stored in the first column and the y-coordinate is the information stored in the second column.

```
document = open("d.csv")
headers = document.readline()

def generateArrays(document):
    for theData in document:
        editDocument = theData.strip().split(",")
        array = np.array((editDocument[0], editDocument[1]))
    return array 

print(generateArrays(document))
```

When I call the function and print it out I was expecting to see 30 different 2D arrays printing out. Instead however I only see this:
[1, 29], which is the information stored in the first row of the CSV file. I tested the for loop outside of the function and it returned back 30, 2D arrays which is leading me to believe that perhaps the return statement is wrong. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The iteration variable is `theData`, but you use `numbers.strip...`.  `numbers` is defined anywhere.  Later you assign `array=...` deep in the loop, but don't accumulate the values from one iteration to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason not to use the numpy library way of handling this? Not sure if I'm missing something.

```
np.genfromtxt('sample.csv', skip_header=1, usecols=(0,1), delimiter=',')
```

Source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: I’m new to numpy so I haven’t learnt much about the entire library. This was my attempt to solve the problem given the tools I’ve learnt

Comment: No worries! Just wanted to let you know there was an easier way, there was some stuff missing from your initial code snippet such as what "numbers" was so I wasn't able to figure it out from that perspective.

Answer (score 0):

@OsmosisJonesLoL's way is great, but there is another option. You could use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to open a .csv file, and then iterate every row and slice the first two columns, then print it.

```
import csv
DOCUMENT = 'file.csv'

def generate_arrays(document):
    file = csv.reader(open(document), delimiter=',')
    for row in file:
        print(row[:2])

generate_arrays(DOCUMENT)
```

Or you could just append every 2-d array to the empty list.

```
import csv
DOCUMENT = 'file.csv'

def generate_arrays(document):
    arrays = []
    file = csv.reader(open(document), delimiter=',')
    for row in file:
        arrays.append(row[:2])
    return arrays

print(generate_arrays(DOCUMENT))
```

Regarding the piece of code, you are posted. I didn't exactly understand where `theData` and `numbers` are coming from? I guess it should be the same variable. The code should actually return the last row, not the first one.
To return every 2-d array you need to append every row to the empty array first, then return it. And you don't actually need to use the numpy `array` method here.

Also be careful with the `open` method, since you need to explicitly close the file after you done with it. So it's more convenient to use the with statement. It makes sure that the file is closed after we are done reading its contents.
Note that `line_slices[:2]` is equals to `[line_slices[0], line_slices[1]]`

```
DOCUMENT = 'file.csv'

def generate_arrays(document):
    array = []
    with open(document) as file:
        for line in file:
            line_slices = line.split(",")
            array.append(line_slices[:2])
        return array

print(generate_arrays(DOCUMENT))
```